# how to send message from flash to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a HTML page that it has an flash(swf) file. in flash file, I have a radio button. I want to call a javascript(or jquery) function when flash radio button is selected. is this possible? if yes how?

Comment: May be useful: AS3 [`ExtertalInterface.addCallback`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29), [`ExternalInterface.call`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29). Also, is it necessary to go down the _Flash_ path? Will _HTML5_ not work for you?

Comment: how can I use HTML5 for this porpose?

Comment: @fullOfQuestions I meant instead of using a `.swf`

Comment: no I should use flash file. I'm working on a project using [CTAT](http://ctat.pact.cs.cmu.edu) and I have to use adobe flash.